# "No input file specified" from php-fpm for 1-2 min after restart

Tags: nginx, php

Using php-fpm with nginx, everything works OK, except for about 1-2 minutes after php-fpm is restarted.  During that period, "No input file specified" is returned for **all** .php URLs.  After 1-2 minutes, everything goes back to normal without further action.

Example entry in /var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
2014/03/04 09:21:22 [error] 1206#0: *55 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/nginx/html (Success)", client: xxx.aaa.bbb.ccc, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /xxx/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
```

Here's the server block from server.conf:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.php index.html;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.+)$;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_pass php;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

And /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
http {
    ...

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    charset utf-8;
    gzip on;
    gzip_static on;
    etag on;
    upstream php {
      server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
    open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    expires max;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?  The fact that it is only happening for a brief period after restarting php-fpm seems to rule out some common problems (e.g. permissions) and seems more like caching?  Thanks!

Comment: How do you restart php-fpm, and can you post the fpm config for the pool?

Comment: And at the risk of trying things are random, change the fastcgi_pass line to "fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;" ?

Comment: @Danack restarting with `/etc/rc.d/init.d/php-fpm restart` (CentOS). I've put a copy of `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` at [link](http://pastebin.com/UcaBxngc).

Comment: also , why are you re-starting php-fpm?

Comment: @Danack there could be many reasons to restart php-fpm, e.g. changing config files. Ordinarily it would not be restarted frequently, so the problem equates to a small (e.g. 0.01%) amount of downtime.  Still, I don't understand why it is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved the problem.  It was necessary to add `/usr/share/nginx/html` (or more generally, `$document_root`) to the `open_basedir` path in either php.ini or the nginx config.  This works:

```
location ~ \.php {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "open_basedir=$document_root";
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_pass php;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

Commenting out the PHP_VALUE causes the problem to return.  I still don't understand *why* the problem occurred or why this solves it; whether it was something to do with php-fpm, APC, nginx, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

That's really weird. This probably isn't an answer as such, but here follows far too much text to fit in a little comment box.

1) The error is definitely coming from PHP-FPM, and isn't a cache problem. The error message is coming from: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c#1920 due to PHP not being able to open the script.

Apparently `zlog` errors get written to the stderr PHP log - which you have set to /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log. Is there anything in there? If not you may need to either recompile PHP, or tweak your log settings to find out what the error is.

2) Running PHP-FPM as nginx user is kind of weird. Nginx needs to run as a privileged process as it listens to port 80, PHP-FPM doesn't. I usually create a user per website, and then have the PHP-FPM pool for each site run under that user. Probably not related to your issue - but who knows.

3) Not being open a file is *really* weird and I don't understand it at all. You may need to run strace to figure out what is actually happening, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prevent strace from abbreviating arguments?
# You want the -s strsize option, which specifies the maximum length of a string to display (the default is 32).

rm -rf trc/*.trc

additional_strace_args="$1"

mkdir trc

MASTER_PID=$(ps auwx | grep php-fpm | grep -v grep | grep 'master process'  | cut -d ' ' -f 7)



# ls -l /tmp/foobar | awk '{print $1"\t"$9}'
# This code takes some input, such as this:
# -rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root            1 Jul 14  1997 tmpmsg
# and generates output like this:
# -rw-rw-rw-      tmpmsg




#shows total of calls
summarise=""
# summarise="-c"


nohup strace -r $summarise -p $MASTER_PID -ff -o ./trc/master.follow.trc >"trc/master.$MASTER_PID.trc" 2>&1 &

while read -r pid;
do
    if [[ $pid != $MASTER_PID ]]; then

        #shows individual calls
        #nohup strace -r -p "$pid" $additional_strace_args >"trc/$pid.trc" 2>&1 &

        #shows total of calls
        nohup strace -r $summarise -p "$pid" $additional_strace_args >"trc/$pid.summary.trc" 2>&1 &
    fi
done < <(pgrep php-fpm)


read -p "Strace running - press [Enter] to stop"

pkill strace
```

btw I'm going to go ahead and guess that you have long running php-fpm scripts. The restart command you're using are doing a graceful restart. If one of the scripts is taking ages, that would probably explain the behaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

> Using open_basedir will disable the realpath cache.